# Resonance structures of some aromatic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, resonance, heterocyclic-compounds

Do compounds like tropolone, furan, and thiophene (which are aromatic) show resonance?

[image: Compounds mentioned in question]

If yes then what are the resonance structures that can be drawn? Also, do all aromatic compounds show resonance?

Comment: I think aromaticity by definition implies resonance

Comment: Binary is right. A prerequisite for aromaticity is cyclic conjugation. Conjugation in itself allows resonance.
Although do not confuse resonance with aromaticity. Resonance is a necessary, but not sufficient condition for aromaticity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Resonance structures can be drawn for **all** aromatic compounds.  Tropolone, furan and thiophene are considered to be aromatic compounds because

- we can draw resonance structures
- and they are cyclic compounds with 4n+2 (n=1) pi electrons

Here are the resonance structures we can draw for **tropolone**, the positive charge can be delocalized to every carbon in the ring.

[image]

Just like in benzene, where instead of drawing 2 resonance structures (top of following figure) we usually just draw the one resonance structure shown at the bottom of the figure;

[image]

instead of drawing all 8 resonance structures for tropolone, we usually represent them by just drawing the one resonance structure shown at the bottom of the tropolone figure.

and here are the resonance structures for **furan**

[image]

and for **thiophene**, they are the same as furan, just replace the oxygen with a sulfur atom in the resonance structures.