# Is a pyrylium ring aromatic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, heterocyclic-compounds, aromaticity

I am trying to figure out which rings in callistephin are aromatic:

[image: Structure of callistephin with pyrylium ring highlighted]

I know that the benzene rings definitely are aromatic, but I'm not sure about the ring with the positively charged oxygen (highlighted in red).

How does the Hückel $4n+2$ rule apply to this ring?

Comment: If you take *both* the rings together, you get a hetero-naphthalene which is aromatic. Other than that you *should* have asked your [former question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/38655/7475) in a more general way that would have allowed answering both in the same way.

Comment: @Jan can I ask how many pi-electrons are in this hetero-napthalene?

Comment: 10, just like in normal naphthalene. (Substitute the $\ce{O+}$ with $\ce{CH}$ and you get naphthalene; that was what I was playing at.)

Answer (score 1):

Pyrylium is aromatic. Following Hückel's rule, pyrylium is uninterrupted (no $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridization), all atoms have p-orbitals and there is 6 π electrons. the 6 π electrons indicate that Hückel's rule $(4n+2)$ is agreeable for pyrylium, $n = 1$.

Comment: Hückel's rules only apply to monocycles.