# Non - aromatic nature of quinones

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

I have read that quinone systems are conjucated but not anti-aromatic. I had read the related questions:

1. [Is the aromaticity broken in some resonance structures of para-nitro-aminobenzene?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22100/is-the-aromaticity-broken-in-some-resonance-structures-of-para-nitro-aminobenzen)
2. [Is a quinone ring aromatic?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38655/is-a-quinone-ring-aromatic).

In one of those answers, I read a point which said that it was non aromatic:

> [...] and you must be able to draw double bonds - internal to the ring
>   - from each ring carbon atom. [...]

I don't get what this means as I had never heard of such a thing in Hückel's rule. I did read elsewhere that the system must be completely conjugated which is true in this case but due to cross conjugation the electrons are not delocalised throughout the system? I don't get why cross conjugation affects the delocalisation of the electrons this much? What is the proper explanation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you must be able to draw double bonds within the ring is **the $4n+2$ rule applies rigorously only when the conjugated atoms are all in such a ring.** If you are drawing double bonds to adjacent atoms off the ring then you don't have all the conjugated pi electrons in the ring anymore, and then there is no longer a $4n+2$ rule for aromaticity or a $4n$ rule for antiaromaticity.

In some systems it is possible to render contributing structures that have all the conjugated electrons in the ring and meet the $4n+2$ rule, in which case you can assert that this contribution is enhanced by aromaticity and the properties of the compound affected accordingly.  For example, the aromatic contribution to [cyclopropenones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclopropenone) leads to enhanced polarity of the carbonyl group and increased basic character of the oxygen atom, compared with ordinary ketones.

[image]

Illustration source: https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:C3H2OResonance.png.  Drawn by WP user Smokefoot.  [Link to License](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode)

Quinones, however, cannot be given such a structure without leaving the highly electronegative oxygen short of an octet, so they lack any significant aromatic contribution.