# Aromaticity of Tropone

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, aromaticity

When we are determining if a given compound is aromatic using Hückel's rule, we count the number of delocalized $\pi$ electrons.

In tropone for example, if I wanted to count the number of delocalized $\pi$ electrons, should I count the $\pi$ electrons of the $\ce{C=O}$ bond?

Or is the aromaticity of tropone because we can draw a more stable aromatic resonating structure in which the $\ce{C}$ acquires a positive charge and the $\ce{O}$ a negative charge?

Comment: See also: [Do the π-electrons from the C=O bond in tropone contribute to Hückel 's rule?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20170/do-the-π-electrons-from-the-c-o-bond-in-tropone-contribute-to-hückel-s-rule)